# Formula to change ID in table of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have table in which my **id**'s are completely random. I would like to update table and set **id** according to **type_id**.

The formula should looks like that: (type_id * 100) + nextval. Nextval should be connected with **id**'s with same **type_id**. How can I make it? **Name** column doesn't matter.

Real state:

```
id       name     type_id
-------  -------  -------
131        V4       1
263        V2       2
339        V3       2
458        V1       1
```

Expected:

```
id       name     type_id
-------  -------  -------
101        V4       1
201        V2       2
202        V3       2
102        V1       1
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If `id` is the primary key, then its value is completely meaningless. The only job it has to do is to be unique.

Comment: I changed sequence when I am adding new records. I have to change it to avoid big mess.

Comment: All you need to do is to adjust the sequence to the max value of the `id` column (e.g. `setval('your_sequence', (select max(id) from the_table))`. Changing primary key values for aesthetic reasons is a waste of time.

Comment: Unfortunately I implement sequence in java code. Can I create sequence according to formula  (type_id * 100) + nextval?